# apache2 запись в корень фс /

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2

Есть сервер ubuntu и apache2 с php.
Нужно apache2 дать доступ на запись в корневой /tmp.
Пробовал каталогу назначить права 777 и

`chown www-data. /tmp`

Не помогает.

В Centos такое решается настройкой selinux.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что не помогло?

Comment: Я попытался что то записать через php скриптом.
скрипт от сюда взял

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php